# Anonymous class replaced with lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-class, java-8

I have sample code which uses Java 8 new [stream functionality](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (get a range of int values 1 .. 20, skip the first 9, then take remaining 10, each int value: reduce by one and multiply by 2).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).skip(9).limit(10).map((new IntUnaryOperator() {
        @Override
        public int applyAsInt(int operand) {
            return operand - 1;
        }
    }).andThen(new IntUnaryOperator() {
        @Override
        public int applyAsInt(int operand) {
            return operand * 2;
        }
    })).toArray()));
```

The output is as follows:

```
[18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36]
```

Now I want to replace anonymous classes with [Lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). The following conversion works fine (the second anonymous class replaced with `i -> i * 2` lambda expression) and I get the same output:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).skip(9).limit(10).map((new IntUnaryOperator() {
        @Override
        public int applyAsInt(int operand) {
            return operand - 1;
        }
    }).andThen(i -> i * 2)).toArray()));
```

However, when I replace the first anonymous class with lambda expression:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).skip(9).limit(10)
            .map((v -> v - 1).andThen(i -> i * 2)).toArray()));
```

I am not able to compile my code. The error says `Operator '-' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int'`

[image: Compilation error]

Do you know how to combine two lambda expressions with `IntUnaryOperator.andThen`?

I know I could use ... `.limit(10).map(v -> v - 1).map(i -> i * 2).toArray() ...` which works fine but I would like to find out how to use `IntUnaryOperator.andThen` with lambdas (if that possible).

Comment: Interesting question! Also the more formal `((int v) -> v - 1).andThen((int i) -> i * 2)` does not work: "error: lambda expression not expected here".

Comment: the compiler cannot infer the type of `(v -> v - 1).andThen(i -> i * 2)` since it actually has to make 2 inferences and then a third out of those two. it most likely is beyond the scope of the type system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast the first lambda expression to IntUnaryOperator. The following code works:

```
System.out.println(
        Arrays.toString(
                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).skip(9).limit(10)
                        .map(((IntUnaryOperator) v -> v - 1).andThen(i -> i * 2)).toArray()));
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to point out that the reason the cast is necessary is that the lambda by itself doesn't have a type.  It only receives a type through assignment/casting. For example, the expression `s -> s.isEmpty()` could be assigned to `java.util.function.Predicate<String>`, `java.util.function.Function<String,Boolean>`, `com.google.common.base.Predicate<String>`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to compile the code as the following (although using eclipse experimental versions):

```
IntUnaryOperator first = v -> v - 1;
IntUnaryOperator second = i -> i * 2;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).skip(9)
                .limit(10).map(first.andThen(second)).toArray()));
```

I understand your interest to be able to write the code without declaring `first` and `second`; however, `IntUnaryOperator` is a `FunctionalInterface` and based on how Java compiler works, a `FunctionalInterface` needs to have a "context" to be able to be composed the way you want it. This is why with your original code snippet Java compiler does not have a way to map your lamda expression to exactly an instance of `IntUnaryOperator`.

For a longer discussion take a look at this thread: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2013-June/002668.html

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to use the static `IntUnaryOperator.identity()` as a startpoint:

```
IntUnaryOperator.identity().andThen(v -> v - 1).andThen(i -> i * 2)
```

With static imports you can use just `identity()` too!

If `IntUnaryOperator` had a static method like...

```
static IntUnaryOperator first(IntUnaryOperator op) { return op; }
```

... we could simply write:

```
IntUnaryOperator.first(v -> v - 1).andThen(i -> i * 2)
```

Comment: It's easy to write your own static `first` method.